# Embedded MongoDB in Spring Boot App can't connect with Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-shell

I am running a Spring Boot app that has MongoDB embedded in it.  When I start the app, MongoDB starts and a DB called 'testdb' is created.  If I launch a mongo shell and do 'show dbs', 'testdb' is not listed.  If I use Postman to POST data to MongoDB I can get it back with the GET, so I know MondoDB is working in the app.

How, if possible, can I connect to this embedded instance of MongoDB so I can test it with the shell?

Comment: How have you configured and launched embedded Mongo?

Comment: I believe the Spring Boot app when started either from the packaged jar or from within Eclipse, mongodb is started as an embedded instance; however, what I don't understand is that I have to start mongod from a Terminal command in order for either the jar instance or eclipse instance of the app to use mongodb.  That is why I assumed I should be able to connect to the dbs that the app was using.

Comment: Spring Boot will only automatically start an embedded Mongo instance if you're using 1.3.0 and you've got `de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` on the classpath. It's impossible to tell whether that's the case from the information you've provided. Perhaps you could read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question accordingly?

Comment: I do not have `de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo`, I have `spring-boot-starter=data=mongodb-1.2.5.RELEASE`.  Which I am assuming is in fact, as you say, starting an embedded instance.  That was what my original question was.  How to connect to an embedded instance with the mongodb shell.